# Compiling R functions to JavaScript with Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c, r, emscripten

I'm trying to compile some R functions, written in C, to JavaScript using Emscripten. My first mission is to port a function called `pf`.

The source can be found [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/pf.c#L28). So, I go into the src directory and try running:

```
(trunk)⚡ % emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_Rf_pf']" nmath/pf.c
warning: unresolved symbol: Rf_pbeta
warning: unresolved symbol: Rf_pchisq
warning: unresolved symbol: R_NaN
warning: unresolved symbol: R_NegInf
warning: unresolved symbol: R_PosInf
```

I get a function `_Rf_pf` in the output JavaScript. I can actually call this function and it returns a result. But, because `R_PosInf` and company are not resolved, it short circuits on `R_P_bounds_01(x, 0., ML_POSINF);`. `ML_POSINF` is somehow set to 0 giving weird results. So, the heart of the algorithm is not executed.

Does anyone know how I can get these symbols resolved and get this function ported?

I can try to compile more source and that seems to get me somewhere:

```
$ emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_Rf_pf']" nmath/pf.c nmath/pbeta.c nmath/pchisq.c 
warning: unresolved symbol: R_finite
warning: unresolved symbol: Rf_pgamma
warning: unresolved symbol: Rf_warning
warning: unresolved symbol: bratio
warning: unresolved symbol: gettext
warning: unresolved symbol: R_NaN
warning: unresolved symbol: R_NegInf
warning: unresolved symbol: R_PosInf
```

But, this seems to lead me down a huge rabbit hole. And, then, I hit some snags:

```
 $ emcc -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_Rf_pf']" nmath/pf.c nmath/pbeta.c nmath/pchisq.c main/arithmetic.c 
In file included from main/arithmetic.c:35:
include/Defn.h:201:3: error: SIZE_MAX is required for C99
# error SIZE_MAX is required for C99
  ^
include/Defn.h:639:9: error: unknown type name 'R_size_t'
extern0 R_size_t R_NSize  INI_as(R_NSIZE);/* Size of cons cell heap */
        ^
include/Defn.h:640:9: error: unknown type name 'R_size_t'
extern0 R_size_t R_VSize  INI_as(R_VSIZE);/* Size of the vector heap */
        ^
...
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

Note that I have CPATH set. I don't know if this is the way to go about pointing the compiler to different headers I need:

```
(trunk)⚡ % echo $CPATH
gnuwin32/fixed/h/:/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/include/:/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.2_1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/include/:nmath/:include/:main/:include/R_ext
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `gnuwin32/fixed/h/config.h`, `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H` is needed.

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/gnuwin32/Makefile

Comment: Thanks, good information. But, it doesn't help much. I got a non-windows config.h from running `./configure` and I'm including it now with -DHAVE_CONFIG_H but the problem remains the same.