# Where can I find an R-to-JavaScript compiler?

Tags: javascript, r

After learning about `dplyr` and `ggplot2`, I've decided to start coding exclusively in R.  Where can I find an R-to-JavaScript compiler, so I can build extensions for Google Chrome?

I am willing to write one myself, but it would have to be in R.

Comment: Personally I believe in using the right tool for the job rather than one tool for everything. Plus, if an R-to-native JS interpreter does indeed exist, I wouldn't necessarily trust the output to be exactly what you want (though some may disagree with that). R and JS were designed for entirely different purposes. Best to use the one that makes sense for the situation.

Comment: The notion that there would be such a thing seems rather fanciful. There are packages that might be of interest but the path to web integration is unlikely to be through an R->JavaScript compiler. You should probably be searching for `shiny` and packages that integrate with `d3`

Comment: A way to pass data from R to Javascript is via the [htmlwidgets  package](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/). Many R packages for data visualisation (e.g. shiny, leaflet) use this mechanism. The [introduction for developers](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html) is short and quite readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R works well as a special purpose math oriented language purely because the R interpreter/JIT and runtime is highly optimized.

Not unlike MATLAB or Mathematica or even using numpy with python

If you were to transpile R code to JS, it would be quite poor in comparision and would be unable to efficiently perform all the complicated computations you would typically do in an R program (if your R code is really doing non-trivial computations)

There doesn't seem to be any project that does R to JS compilation - seems like it is not really something people would really require.

I think the ecosystem of Javascript only Chrome extensions is a poor fit for running R code in.

If you were running FireFox or IE, you could call DLLs from within extensions - using COM on IE and the FF native bridge API. Chrome doesn't support such a thing directly.

The answer is to write an NPAPI plugin - this is a bit of native code implemented as a DLL that can be accessed from JS, via an OBJECT tag. I have used this to write an extension that replaces Flash video controls with a windowless VLC player on Chrome, FF and IE. 
This is the best way to do it. Write your R code, make it a DLL, expose the interface via an NPAPI plugin. In your extension, inject an OBJECT tag into the HTML, which will instantiate your native code instance - after which you can call methods on it directly as if it were a JS object.

The next best thing I can think of is - Translate R to MATLAB, convert MATLAB to C++ (which is possible) and then run the C++ as native client code in the browser.

Comment: NPAPI is not supported anymore in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Some of R's built-in functions are written in C, so it might be possible to [compile R to JavaScript using Emscripten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573314/compiling-r-functions-to-javascript-with-emscripten).